# Email signature not scaling properly on Gmail mobile app

Tags: html, css, ios, gmail, signature

I am building a HTML signature that is working well on desktop and mobile Outlook and desktop Gmail. I am stuck at making it look nice on Gmail iOS app. The signature is being scaled down properly on Outlook mobile: fonts, images are scaling down and the table in which the signature is located is occupying the whole width.

But on Gmail app, it's not scaling down: the images and fonts are the same size as the desktop and everything looks bad, [see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy9SW.jpg).

Here's the code:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Email Signature</TITLE>
<META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v17/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVZ0d.woff) format('woff');
  mso-font-alt: 'Arial'; }
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v17/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN7rgOUuhv.woff) format('woff');
  mso-font-alt: 'Arial'; }
}
</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;">
    ddd
<table style="width: 525px; font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td width="150" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; width: 150px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top" rowspan="6"> <a href="https://avanti.ca/" target="_blank"><img class="profilepic" border="0" alt="Profile picture" width="150" style="width:150px; height:auto; border:0;" src="https://avanti.ca/signatures/images/userpic.png"></a>
  </td>
 <td style="padding-left:10px">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 10pt; color:#009787; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; width: 400px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 10px; vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
       <strong><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; color:#009787;">Farkhod Fayzullaev</span></strong><span><br></span>
       <strong style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:8pt; color:#333333; text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px;">Digital Marketing Manager</strong><span><br></span>
       <span style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10pt; color:#333333;">403-555-7895 ext 112</span>
      </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 10pt; color:#333333; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 10px; vertical-align: top; line-height:19px;" valign="top">    <strong><span>    <span style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:11pt; color:#333333;">Avanti Software</span>    </span></strong>  <span><br></span> <span><span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; color:#333333;">Build a Better Workplace</span></span> 
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="border-left: 2px solid #999; padding-left: 30px; vertical-align: middle;" valign="middle">
          <span><a href="https://www.greatplacetowork.ca/en/best-workplaces/all-certified-companies#certified-organizations/view-sub-list-details/5b0842f21dd2d7498d2eeaf7/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="70" height="70" alt="Great Place To Work icon" style="border:0; height:70px; width:70px;" src="https://avanti.ca/signatures/images/gpw.png">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-left: 10px; vertical-align: bottom;" valign="bottom">
        <span><a href="https://www.facebook.com/AvantiSoftware/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="19" alt="facebook icon" style="border:0; height:19px; width:19px;" src="https://avanti.ca/signatures/images/fb.png"></a>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://twitter.com/AvantiHCM" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="19" alt="twitter icon" style="border:0; height:19px; width:19px;" src="https://avanti.ca/signatures/images/tw.png"></a>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://www.glassdoor.ca/Overview/Working-at-Avanti-Software-EI_IE384910.11,26.htm" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="19" alt="glassdoor icon" style="border:0; height:19px; width:19px;" src="https://avanti.ca/signatures/images/gd.png"></a>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/avantisoftware" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="19" alt="linkedin icon" style="border:0; height:19px; width:19px;" src="https://avanti.ca/signatures/images/li.png"></a>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="https://www.instagram.com/avantisoftware/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img border="0" width="19" alt="instagram icon" style="border:0; height:19px; width:19px;" src="https://avanti.ca/signatures/images/ig.png"></a>&nbsp;</span>
      </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
</table>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Is there any way to scale the whole HTML down in Gmail iOS app?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Just shared, thanks!